# Count IFS with two conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

I have an excel table that contains three columns. I need to set a value in column C (status) that depends on column A and B. If all the values in column B contain the term "Apple" and "Pear" for a fixed value in column A then each row in column C needs to say "Yes" otherwise "No".

In the example screenshot the status is "Yes" for ID = 1000 because the term "Apple" and "Pear" appears in column B while for ID = 2000 it says "No" because it doesn't contain both conditions.

I am using the following formula `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,{"Apple","Pear"})=0,"No","Yes")` which is setting everything to "Yes", and i think i am approaching this in the wrong way.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: You say ‘table’ but this appears to be an Excel question.  If so, please tag accordingly, or clarify the question.

Comment: Additionally, what about `=IF(AND(COUNTIF ...`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be the following:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,{"Apple","Pear"}))=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: If you change "Orange" to "Pear" on the table you would expect the status to update to "Yes" for ID = 2000, but it seems to returns a "No" value.

Comment: No repro. Works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0h97.png